# Percentile vs percentile_approx in SparkSQL

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using percentile in one of my sql's but due to large data skewness, the query is failing with out of memory error. Even after increasing memory, the query is failing. I found this percentile_approx function which works on my dataset but there are differences between percentile and percentile_approx.

Can some kind soul please explain the differences?

My dataset contains dollar amounts up to 2 decimal points. The number of rows will vary from month to month but it's usually over 300 million rows.

Thanks

Comment: 300million rows will cause perf issues. 1. can we partition on some row like year/country etc? 2. if not, then i would may be put the data separately into a smaller table, calculate separately and try to see if thats causing perf issues.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Can't partition or put the data into smaller table. These 300 mil rows are already a subset of the total dataset.